# How to disable Logging when start turbogear2?

Tags: python, turbogears2, turbogears

I would like to disable the logging in this picture (in the red box):

[image]

I use **turbogears 2.3.7**. When I start gearbox server and access my url http://localhost:8778. in log will show access url.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2016 16:59:06] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2016 16:59:06] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2016 16:59:06] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2016 16:59:06] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the fact that you are serving app with the `wsgiref` server. You can see that by the fact that you have `use = egg:gearbox#wsgiref` inside your `[server:main]` section of the `development.ini` file.

The `wsgiref` server, being only meant for development doesn't have a proper logging configuration, and just outputs everything to `stderr`.

If you want to manage logging you can switch to a better suited server like **Waitress**.

Just `pip install waitress` and then in your `development.ini` put something like:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
```

in place of

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gearbox#wsgiref
```